How to make Region from Spline curve
Let
bsf = BSplineFunction[{{1, 1}, {-0.5, -0.7}, {-0.4, -1}, {1, 0}}, 
  SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> 3]


Than
ParametricRegion[bsf[t], {{t, 0, 1}}]

not work:

Also not work
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@
 BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, .5}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  SplineClosed -> True]

What am I doing wrong?


BSplineCurve+BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics.

BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@
 BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, .5}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  SplineClosed -> True]



BSplineFunction+Indexed+ ParametricRegion+ BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics

Clear[bsf]; 
bsf = 
 BSplineFunction[{{1, 1}, {-0.5, -0.7}, {-0.4, -1}, {1, 0}}, 
  SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> 3];
ParametricRegion[{Indexed[bsf[t], 1], 
     Indexed[bsf[t], 2]}, {{t, 0, 1}}] // DiscretizeRegion // 
  Show // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics

Or
bsf = BSplineFunction[{{1, 1}, {-0.5, -0.7}, {-0.4, -1}, {1, 0}}, 
   SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> 3];
ParametricPlot[bsf@t, {t, 0, 1}] // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics



curve = 
 BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, .5}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   SplineClosed -> True];

region = DiscretizeGraphics @ Graphics[FilledCurve @ curve]


Head @ region


MeshRegion

